# error Https for jquery library when change http to https mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I changed my app port a few days ago(`Mvc` app -> `http` to `https`).

When changed, I see the error in the console in my browser:

[image]

How to resolve it?

Comment: Please post the error message as text here - it is unreadable from the screenshot.

Comment: You nee to access the jquery over https. Replace http with https in all of your jquery plugins urls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not only do you have to secure your site with a certificate (which it seems you have done), you have to make every resource you load from your site requested via HTTPS as well.  For example:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
```

Should be

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
```

I tested it and `code.jquery.com` supports HTTPS URLs